# Changing the behavior of Vista/Windows 7 "All Programs" menu to be like XP

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista, start-menu

I'd like to have the "All Programs" menu in the Vista/Windows 7 Start Menu behave like it does in Windows XP, *without* changing to the "Classic" start menu.  Specifically, I'd like the All Programs menu to expand vertically (the more programs are on the menu the higher it goes) and horizonally (as submenus expand) unbounded by the Start Menu dialog as it currently does.  I find it more difficult to visualize the set programs installed with the current view.  Switching back to the Classic menu would do this but then I'd lose the other goodies such as iterative search.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Not solving your problem, but have you tried to get used to the search? I find it many times more efficient.

Comment: Definitely - in fact I use both.  When I don't know exactly what I want I'll expand all programs and usually will get a visual reminder of what I'm looking for, and/or the other options I've got to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**This**](http://www.askvg.com/get-windows-xp-styled-classic-all-programs-list-in-windows-vista/) is the closest alternative I've found, which involves swapping out your Favorites for a Programs menu:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found this which I really like... and it's free!

http://classicshell.sourceforge.net

Comment: Nicely brings back the old start menu on Windows 8.x too

Answer (score 2):

Personally I surrendered and have learned to accept the new Start Menu Microsoft has been trying to impose on use since Vista. But if you do not wish to install an application for this, here how to do it (sort of):

The end result will be this:

[image]

Let's have some fun:

First make sure to have your My Documents folder displayed as a Menu on the Start Menu

- Right-Click *Start Menu* and Select
  **Properties**
- From the Start Menu Tab, click
  **Customize...**
- Search for the **Documents** item and
  check **Display as a Menu**. Apply
  and go back to Desktop.

Now we are going to include the Programs folder in that list and remove (if you want) the Documents folders.

- Click the Start Menu and Right-Click
  the **Documents** item on the
  right-hand list. Select
  **Properties**.
- Click **Include a Folder...** and
  navigate to
  `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start
  Menu\Programs`. **Click Include
  Folder**.
- If you wish you can now remove the
  two documents folders by selecting
  them one at a time and clicking
  **Remove**. Don't worry. You can see a *Restore Defaults* button down that
  dialog box which will put everything
  back in place in case you don't like
  it.
- Accept your changes.

One final touch

- Right-Click The **Documents** item on
  the Start Menu again and select
  **Rename**.
- Rename it to `Programs`.

And Voilá!

Restoring it to what it used to be before is a no-brainer. Simply click that *Restore Defaults* button we discussed above and **rename** the Programs item back to *Documents*.

Comment: I can see JohnT answer. It's an even better method to this since it doesn't imply reusing an existing menu item like I'm doing here. I'm leaving this answer for the sake of completeness (and because it gave me a lot of trouble to write). But my +1 goes to him.

Comment: Hmm.. actually it does reuse an item. On this case, the Favorites item. Still I find it more elegant than my approach.

Answer (score 1):

See the freeware [Vista Start Menu](http://www.vistastartmenu.com/index.html), it's even better than what you're asking for.

[image: image1]

Another less-flexible option is [CSMenu](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/2227/get-the-classic-start-menu-in-windows-7/):

[image: image2]

Comment: Hi Harry great find.  I like this and am going to bookmark it for future.  I'm going to start with John T's answer though because it's a native solution.  Thanks!